# what VsCode theme enables nice handwriting font on html attributes?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Which theme adds the nice font for html attributes ? [image]

Answer (score 0):

That's actually not a characteristic of a VSCode theme, but rather an attribute of the [Operator Mono](https://www.typography.com/fonts/operator/styles/) font. It's become a pretty popular font choice recently, but it's definitely not cheap.
Although a few users have also made alternatives to popular VSCode themes that utilize *italics* more frequently for use with Operator Mono, such as [Oceanic Next Italic](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SintrumIT.theme-oceanic-next-italic).

Answer (score 0):

Operator Mono is pretty popular & expensive. There are a couple alternatives. The first being Dank Mono which costs around 45 us dollars. I personally use this font and love it. You can check it out here https://dank.sh/

Also, there is Fira Code which does not have the "handwriting" / cursive but it does make use of ligatures just like Operator & dank Mono. Take a look here https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode

Comment: Never bad to comment on an old thread if you have good information! The links seem good, but please add some additional content if you can, like examples of the fonts you're suggesting. Generally, link-only answers are discouraged, but it is kind of what this post seems to be asking for. I think the pictures would help though.